# Solutions of em potentials in Lorenz's gauge

Tags: electromagnetism, gauge-invariance

When we solve the equations for em potentials in Lorenz's gauge:

$ \nabla \cdot \textbf{A} + \frac{1}{c^2} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial t} = 0$

we find the solutions:

$\phi (\textbf{x}, t) = \frac{1}{4 \pi \epsilon_0} \int d^3 \textbf{x}' \frac{\rho(\textbf{x}', t_r) }{\lvert \textbf{x} - \textbf{x}' \rvert } $

$\textbf{A} (\textbf{x}, t) = \frac{\mu_0}{4 \pi} \int d^3 \textbf{x}' \frac{\textbf{J}(\textbf{x}', t_r) }{\lvert \textbf{x} - \textbf{x}' \rvert } $,

with $t_r = t-\frac{\lvert \textbf{x}-\textbf{x}' \rvert}{c} $.

My question is: once we have the solutions, shouldn't we check that in fact they do solve Lorenz's gauge?

For example when we solved the equations in the vacuum with Coulomb's gauge we had to impose the condition $\nabla \cdot \textbf{A} = 0 $ after we found a solution. This resulted in the transverse nature of em waves.

Comment: By all means, do check. The following relationship, derivable from Maxwell's equations should come in handy: $\partial_t \rho + \boldsymbol{\nabla}.\mathbf{J}=0$

Comment: Use integration by parts to change $\boldsymbol{\nabla}\to\boldsymbol{\nabla}'$

Comment: Oh, yes, I have already! It's just that every textbook I have seen so far gives it for granted and doesn't even bother to check or say it should be checked and I was wondering if it was somehow trivial